# NextJS dynamic routes /[optional_path]/[slug].js

Tags: next.js

In NextJS, is it possible to create an optional path in the dynamic route file in some way?

I want to use the same template for mdx pages for routes `/blog/<slug>` or `/<slug>` depending upon the frontmatter key `type` which may equal 'post' or 'page'. If type == 'post', create a `/blog/<slug>` path, else just create `/<slug>` directly.

How do I do this?

Comment: So you want to catch both `/[slug].js` and `/optional_path]/[slug].js`?

Comment: Yes, precisely!

Answer (score 1):

You probably want [optional catch all routes](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes#optional-catch-all-routes):

> Catch all routes can be made optional by including the parameter in double brackets (`[[...slug]]`).
>
> For example, `pages/post/[[...slug]].js` will match `/post`, `/post/a`, `/post/a/b`, and so on.
>
> The main difference between catch all and optional catch all routes is that with optional, the route without the parameter is also matched (`/post` in the example above).
>
> The `query` objects are as follows:
>
> ```json
> { } // GET `/post` (empty object)
> { "slug": ["a"] } // `GET /post/a` (single-element array)
> { "slug": ["a", "b"] } // `GET /post/a/b` (multi-element array)
> ```

Comment: I read that but couldn't make it work. Please read my edited question.

Comment: @redstuck I'm not sure what you mean. Could you clarify?